# NN with Keras predicts classes as dtype=float32 as oppose to true class values of 1,2,3, why?

Tags: neural-network, keras, classification, prediction

I am implementing a simple NN on wine data set. The NN works well and produces the prediction score, however, when I am trying to explore the actual predicted values on the test data set, I receive an array with dtype=float32 values, as oppose to values of the classes.

- The classes are labelled as 1, 2, 3
- I have 13 attributes and 178 observations (small data set)
- Below is the the code on the implementation and the outcome I get:

  `df.head()`
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SucM0.jpg)

  `X=df.ix[:,1:13]`

  `y= np.ravel(df.Type)`

  `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)`

  `scale the data:`

  `scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)`

  `X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)`

  `X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)`

  `define the NN`

  `model = Sequential()`

  `model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu', input_shape=(12,)))`

  `model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))`

  `fit the model`

  `model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`

  `model.fit(X_train, y_train1,epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=1)`

Now this is where I store my predictions into y_pred and get the final score:

```
`y_pred = model.predict(X_test)`

`score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test1,verbose=1)`


`59/59 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
```

[0.1106848283591917, 0.94915255247536356]`

When i explore y_pred I see the following:

```
`y_pred[:5]`

`array([[  3.86571424e-04,   9.97601926e-01,   1.96467945e-03,
      4.67598657e-05],
   [  2.67244829e-03,   9.87006545e-01,   7.04612210e-03,
      3.27492505e-03],
   [  9.50196641e-04,   1.42343721e-04,   4.57215495e-02,
      9.53185916e-01],
   [  9.03929677e-03,   9.63497698e-01,   2.62350030e-02,
      1.22799736e-03],
   [  1.39460826e-05,   3.24015366e-03,   9.96408522e-01,
      3.37353966e-04]], dtype=float32)`
```

Not sure why I do not see the actual predicted classes as 1,2,3?

After trying to convert into int I just get an array of zeros, as all values are so small.

Really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the probabilities for each class. To convert probabilities to class just take the max of each case.

```
import numpy as np
y_pred_class = np.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)
```

Comment: Ioannis, thank you! It has worked, really appreciate it

Comment: You could accept and upvote my answer then, thank you too